# Uploaded file has empty rows Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When user browses files and clicks submit, I have to upload file to public folder location of rails application. I'm successful to upload this.

But uploaded file has empty rows. How to upload file without empty rows?

### Original File

```
1.ID      Division     Organisation
2.EA011  Maintenance   Repairs
3.EA012  Application   Production
```

I have to validate headers across rows and then update UI for every row processed. Say i have to validate ID and then show in a form below submit button in same page where i uploaded file. How can i update form after processing each row. and print ID EA011 is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If a file has empty rows, then it has empty rows--you can't change that. However, you can always remove the empty rows from a file:

```
#Here's a file with an empty row:
File.open('stuff.txt', 'w') do |f|
  f.puts("hello\n\nworld")
end

#Remove the empty rows:
File.open('stuff2.txt', 'w') do |fout|
  IO.foreach('stuff.txt') do |line|
    next if line =~ /\A\s+\z/
    fout.write(line)
  end
end

--output:--
$ ruby myprog.rb
$ cat stuff.txt
hello

world
~/ruby_programs$ cat stuff2.txt
hello
world
```

Comment: Another way (if the file is not huge) is `IO.write('stuff2.text, IO.read('stuff.txt').gsub(/\n{2,}/, "\n"))`.

Comment: But my original file doesnot have empty rows. When i upload file i'm getting empty rows. Followed this tutorial to upload file http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm. Once file is uploaded i'm getting empty rows

Comment: I'm getting a single new line after every row. I'm uploading excel file with .csv extension

Comment: @Bryan T, Copy and paste the first three lines of your file into your original post.

Comment: @BryanT, I meant: copy and paste the first three lines of your original .csv file--not the uploaded file.

Comment: Added my original file

Comment: @BryanT, I examined the characters in your original file, and everything looks okay.  What are you doing to look at your uploaded file? In other words, how do you know there are blank lines inserted?  When I upload your original file, there are no blank lines.  Of course, I'm not using a tutorial that's 20 years old and which takes something very simple and makes it very convoluted and confusing.  What version of rails are you using?  If you are using a current version, then read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Comment: Thanks 7stud. Looks fine Now. After i click submit below that submit button i want to include form and update status of each file row. I had edited my question.

Comment: @BryanT, *Looks fine Now.* -- So no more blank lines?

Comment: @7stud no more empty rows now. Thanks for your post :)

Comment: One thing i couldnot solve is to update  status in same page below submit button. Edited my question.. Could you help me? i'm able to process file and validate row against header. But how to print this in UI i'm stuck at this

Comment: *One thing i couldnot solve is to update status in same page below submit button.*  Put a `<div id="results">` below the submit button.  Then use jquery to listen for the click on the button, and use jquery to submit an ajax request to the proper action in your rails app, then fill in the `<div>` with the results.

Comment: @7stud could you post some code. New to jquery and ajax. Once i click submit i enter to controller where i have logic to process file.

Comment: @BryanT, Web programming is very difficult.  There are many things you have to know: html, javascript/jquery and ajax, the format of requests, a server side language like ruby/rails, and json just for starters.  There are many tutorials on all those subjects.  I suggest you get busy and do some reading--but don't expect to learn web programming in a month.  It takes much longer than that--more like a 6-12 months to get the basics down.

Comment: @7stud Thanks. Will check tutorials. Could you suggest useful links for this. It would be helpful rather than following bad tutorials

Comment: @BryanT, I don't know which tutorials are best. You might want to start with SitePoint, which is a website dedicated to web programming, and it has been around for a long time(10+ years). Here is a jquery tutorial: sitepoint.com/introduction-jquery-shorthand-ajax-methods. Personally, I like books better than tutorials. SitePoint actually publishes some books themselves, and you can check amazon for ratings on the various jQuery books.

Comment: @7stud Thanks. Will check these sites